# Helpt with not working URL redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a little problem with my URL redirect.

This is my htaccess file:

```
ModPagespeed off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^firma/(\d+)*$ index.php?company=$1
```

When I enter my website via `https://example.com/firma/asd/`, I get only the standard 404-page with:

```
Not Found    
The requested URL /firma/asd/ was not found on this server.
```

Can anyone tell me what is from with my redirect? The `index.php` and `.htaccess` file are in the root directory of my webspace.
I played a bit around with the redirect and also deleted the cache in Chrome to make sure, that this is not the problem.

Any advises are welcome.

Comment: (\d+)*$ does not match asd

Comment: Oh, god. Thanks. I was not so firm with redirects and copy+pasted an example and did not pay so much attention to the regex. You saved my day, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(\d+)*$ does not match asd But only numbers or nothing:

```
https://example.com/firma/
https://example.com/firma/123
```

Btw. Better use ^firma/(\d+)?$